# Как сворачивать функции в Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, ide

В Delphi 2010 в листинге программы напротив функций и процедур есть плюсы и минусы, которые разварачивают и сварачивают функцию или процедуру, напротив которой находятся.

А кто-нибудь знает, как сделать так чтоб они одним махом все свернулись? А то приходится на каждый плюс или минус нажимать.

И как можно сохранить проект (листинг) с развернытыми функциями, а некоторые свернутыми? А то при открытии они всегда развернуты. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть какие-нибудь настройки.. в разных IDE обычно бывают настройки.. как минимум "сворачивать всё при открытии".. а иногда и более мудрёные варианты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свернуть все функции: `Ctrl + Shift + K + M`.

Answer (score 1):

Свернуть все функции также можно нажав правой кнопкой мыши в редакторе кода и выбрав пункт меню: Fold -> Methods